# coercing values in R

Tags: r, zero, coerce

I have a text file with email id's which I am reading into R (example 1).  Sometimes the field is blank (example 2).

```
example 1: To: admin@naukrioverseas.com
example 2: To:
```

I am using the following code to read the data:

```
to <- grep(a, pattern = "To:.*", value = T)
to <- unlist(regmatches(to, gregexpr("([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4}))", to)))
```

I have similar other fields such as From, Subject, etc.  Once I extract the values, I am converting them to a data frame.

```
dat <-  data.frame(from, to, date, subj)
```

Whenever I have a file with values absent (example 2), the get an empty character with length 0 which throws an error upon using them to create a data frame.  Is there a way can I coerce a dummy value like "NoID" whenever I get an empty character.  I tried the following but doesn't seem to change anything.

```
to <- if(all(nchar(to) == 0)){
        to == "No mail add"
} else {
        to
}
```

or this:

```
date <- if(is.null(date)){
        date == 0
} else {
        date
}
```

can I coerce a value or NA so that I could parse every mail id?

Comment: You could add `NA`s to zero-length vectors with something like `if(length(x) == 0) NA else x`

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz...your solution worked...however i tried `if(length(to) == 0){to == 'NA"} else {to}`...which i though was similar to your solution...but it didn't work....don't know why

Comment: `to == 'NA'` does not assign to "to" but compares "to" with the character "NA" (not R's `NA`). To assign, you could use `to = if(length(to) == 0) NA else to` or to use directly, you could `data.frame(if(length(to) == 0) NA else to, from)`

Comment: @alexis_laz thank you...good learning for me